# Undefined control sequence \pasa -> Publications of the Astronomical Society of Australia

Tags: bibliographies, errors

So I have the following bibitem

```
\bibitem[Finkelstein(2016)]{2016PASA...33...37F} Finkelstein, S.~L.\ 2016, \pasa, 33, e037
```

That causes texshop to choke -- but only on my desktop Mac. Its fine on my laptop -- which both have the same version of TeXShop installed?!

On the desktop I get the following error ... and I know it doesn't like

```
\pasa
```

because if I change it to \apj it works fine. Anyone have any idea? TeXShop says 'unknown control sequence' for that bib line.

Comment: Do you have the same *distribution* installed? TeXshop is just the IDE.

Comment: Without more information it's impossible to tell. What's certain is that this has nothing whatsoever to do with TeXShop which is just an editor.  Some package or `.bst` file must have defined `\pasa` and you have that in your laptop but not on your desktop. As @Werner suggests perhaps this is to do with having different years of MacTeX although I suspect it's more likely because you have different local `texmf` folders on each machine. Is the `\bibitem` generated by `bibtex` or is it manually created?

Comment: In TeX Live there is only one `.bst` file that defines the macro `\pasa`: the `mnras.bst` file. Assuming you have MacTeX installed on both machines, this should be available. Is this the `.bst` file you are using, or are you using a modified version of it?

Comment: It is manually created (from ads really)... I updated my distribution, (tlmgr) but I guess that must be it. Something in /usr/local/texlive/2016 must be different... I know its not the bibitem since a simple change from \pasa to \apj fixes it (but then includes the incorrect journal).

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem...

I had an older copy (from 2012) of emulateapj.cls in my distribution. I updated to this one which includes the definition for \pasa:

[emulateapj](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~alexey/emulateapj/emulateapj.cls)

Thanks all for pointing me in the right direction.